# Why Heroku loads fewer css js in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is the page source header from Heroku production:

```
<head>
  <title>Gosgf</title>
  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application-e11c07d8fd96415a6de17e941d115bde.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application-786dea1c8b4a7b9d1635fb121196a3f3.js"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
  <meta content="LAzUNgZEUmay9OLVUsN0u6Amz/9BVJngJKvE+B6+L1g=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
```

Here is from 127.0.0.1:3000

```
<head>
  <title>Gosgf</title>
  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/games.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/jgo/jgoboard.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/jgo/jgoboard_small.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/sgfs.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/welcome.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/games.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jgo/all-min.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jgo/autodiv.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jgo/jgoboard.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jgo/sgf.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery/jquery-1.10.1.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery/jquery-1.10.1.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery/jquery.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/sgfs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/welcome.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
  <meta content="8+ZHwU8R9V/V5zgoVL3fqyGKxYG2BxV2f8LtRCZNDAg=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
```

A lot of `js` and `css` under `app/asserts` are ignored by Heroku.

I have already added:

```
 gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

in Gemfile.

Assets are pre-compiled:

```
 RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
 git add public/assets
 git commit -m "compiled assets"
```

before `push`.

In `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
 config.serve_static_assets = true
 config.assets.compile = true
```

How can I tell Heroku to load the `js` and `css` assets?

Answer (score 2):

This is normal - the application.js and application.css that your production page does load should contain all of your application's assets (at least anything that has be included by the application.css or application.js manifests).

This is (among other things) what precompiling does.